# PhpStorm Live Template conflict with tab

Tags: phpstorm, live-templates

I created a HTML live template with some variables, and one of the variables are outside the tags for example a select drop down that defines the name of the select. 
If I press tab to go to the next variable, instead of going to the next variable PhpStorm creates a HTML tag of the name I just typed in.

I have disabled all other HTML templates and it is still doing it. Does anyone know how to check what template is being invoked?

I checked now, if I type anywhere anything in HTML and press tab it will create a tag `<anything></anything>`

So maybe its a keyboard assignment, but I cant find anything. Please help...

Here's my template:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label for="$MODEL$" class="col-sm-3 control-label">$NAME$</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select enter id="$MODEL$" class="form-control" ng-disabled="guest"
                ng-model="$MODEL$"
                ng-options="x in $END$"
        >
            <option value="">Please select a $NAME$...</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please record some gif/screencast that would illustrate the issue. Right now it's not 100% clear on what exactly is happening. But generally speaking: `Tab` can be triggering the Emmet abbreviation expansion in your case. Possible solution -- use `Enter` to jump to next placeholder/variable.

Comment: Cool Thanks, using enter instead works fine!

Answer (score 2):

Instead to use **tab** for `live template`, you can use **Enter** button.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6454 for updates. As a workaround please do not use Tab to jump to next field when expanding live templates - Enter will stop editing current value and move cursor to next one.